# Adding an image and an anchor tag to an element within an array using props in React

Tags: reactjs

While creating cards and using props in React.js I need to add an anchor tag(website:) and an image (image:) within a few elements in an array but am unable to figure out how.  Of course, as seen below simply just adding an anchor tag etc does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const projects = [
{
  id: 1,
  image: <img src="https://picture.jpg" alt="Coaching Website">
  name: "Personal Coaching Website",
  meaning:"A comprehensive website for a personal health and wellness coach"
  website: <a href="https://www.samplewebsite.com"></a>
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than defining elements in an array, use the values, and map into the properties of the element.

```
const projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: "https://picture.jpg",
    name: "Personal Coaching Website",
    meaning: "A comprehensive website for a personal health and wellness coach",
    website: "https://www.samplewebsite.com"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {projects.map(project => {
        return (
          <div>
            <img src={project.image} />
            <a href={project.website} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```